# how to break products and users and orders table in microservice design

Tags: microservices

Assume that I have three table. products, and orders, and users
I can sell my products in three ways. mobile, and desktop version and mobile-web version.

I wanted to know how should I design my microservice. I believe that I need to have users in all of my services, because, for example I need to see list of orders plus who has ordered in my imaginary order service. Additionally, I need to have user in my ProductCatalog service in order to know who has created this product . (Imagine I haven't separated my backend user's and my end users)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest thinking about the data. What are the data types that you have? Who is the producer of each type? Who is the consumer? What is the relationship between data types? What type of queries will be circulated in your system? What does a service need to know in order to reply to a query?

Then plan your services around the data. One **or more** services that produce each type. One **or more** services that consume each type. One **or more** services that reply to each query type.

You would obviously need a runtime engine that supports the suggested model. I can suggest [Spiderwiz](http://spiderwiz.org), an open source programming model and runtime that I believe would fit your needs nicely.